# List not resetting in for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, slice, addition

I am a beginner level coder. I am trying to run a loop and get a list. The code will run different equation (functions) based on user input and compile a list. I want to run the loop and get all the values in my list for the 1st loop, and get 2nd values onwards for the subsequent runs by the loop, and add them into a final list. However, after every loop, the dummy_list is not resetting and I cant get the unique list for that specific loop. It is just adding. I have difficulty specifying to retrieve all values in list from 1st loop and omit the 1st value and retrieve the remaining values in my subsequent loops.

```
for i in range (cycles):
    dummy_list = []
    a = input("type choice: " )
    b = int(input("angle: " ))
    c = int(input("exponent: " ))
    result = equation1 (a , b , c)
    dummy_list = (result[0])

final_list += dummylist[1:]
```

Comment: You should add all the variables to reproduce your code, and the expected output ;)

Comment: You probably want to define `dummy_list = []` outside the loop and in the loop `append` to it?

Answer (score 0):

Comments on your code :

```
for i in range (cycles):
    dummy_list = [] # here you create an empty list
    a = input("type choice: " )
    b = int(input("angle: " ))
    c = int(input("exponent: " ))
    result = equation1 (a , b , c)
    dummy_list = (result[0]) # add one item to empty list
    # at this point dummy_list always has only one element 

final_list += dummylist[1:] # get 2nd and next elements of a one element list
```

What you should do :

- in loop :

  - test if final loop is empty = first run
  - if first run add all result to final list
  - else  add only 2nd results you

Comment: But, the code cant run if the 'for' and 'dummy_list' is on the same indentation.

Comment: Sorry , just formatting problem (I corrected it).it was just for you to see what was happening and why may not have the desired result.

Comment: Note that `dummy_list = (result[0])` _replaces_ the binding to the empty list with `result[0]`, it doesn't get added to the original empty list.